# java compare two values of diffrent classes

Tags: java, class, compare

Let's say I have an Animal class, and a cat and a dog class that extend from the animal class. 
Now I want to see if the dog and the cat have the same name.
I've tried this:

```
if(kitty.getName().equals(doggy.getName()))
```

But it won't let me do this because a cat is not a dog I guess? Is there a way I can still compare? Or do I really not wanna do something like this, if so then why not?

Comment: We need a working example and the error message you are getting, Obviously this is not that.

Comment: Did you really type `equels`? Or was that a type in this question? It's supposed to be `equals`.

Comment: that was a typo sorry

Comment: "it won't let me do this" - why do you say that, did you try it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You can certainly do what you are trying in that line of code. It requires that both the Cat class and the Dog class have a `getName` method (easiest to fulfil by just writing it in the `Animal` superclass) and that it returns a reference type (like `String`, typically) and not `null`. Of course a dog and a cat can have the same name, and of course Java can model that.

Comment: From the question checklist, you are doing most things correctly. It would really (as in _really_) help answering your question if you would pay attention to these two items: “If your code doesn't compile, have you included the exact compiler error?" “If your program throws an exception, have you included the exception, with both the message and the stack trace?”

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly difficult to tell what your problem is from your question without sample code, but let's take the following classes:

Animal class:

```
public abstract class Animal 
{
    String name;

    public Animal(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Cat class:

```
public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public Cat(String name) {
        super(name);
    }   
}
```

Dog class:

```
public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }   
}
```

And this example code:

```
    Cat cat = new Cat("kitty");
    Dog dog = new Dog("doggy");

    if (cat.getName().equals(dog.getName())){
        System.out.println("true");
    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

This will produce the behaviour that I believe you are looking for. Is this different to how your code is structured? Please provide more information so it's easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to provide more information about your program. Let's say the error message, the return type of both getName() method and how you declare your dog and cat class as well as the initialisation in main. For what you had provided, it doesn't make any sense having difficulty on using "equals()" for comparison. Of course, assuming the return type for both methods is the same(like string maybe?)